.NET 8 Blazor Template Creation Failure on Windows 11
I am creating a project with the built in template called: 'Blazor Webassembly Standalone App'
Please see the below screenshots the process:


When I run either in debug and not in debug:

As you can see when I run (to try and see the web so far) I get this error, what can I do to solve this? My friends they created a template in Windows 10 it instantly ran.
In case my specs are:
https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/A5--AMD-Ryzen-5000-Series#kf
I am using Visual Studio Installer 2022 x64
Error:
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[27604] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 2147516546 (0x80008082).

I am expecting to run with WPA to develop without any hiccups as currently it is not even working.

can you try to reinstall .net and then run dotnet --info again? do you get the same error?

Yes, same error.

If you installed .NET SDK from VS Code window after installing the C# Web Kit extension, this error could occur. Uninstall .NET Framework and reinstall it from the official website. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

I would uninstall VS 2022. Reboot PC. reinstall.

None of these worked, maybe I forgot to mention my setup is Visual Studio 2022 Professional?

What I did to fix this issue:
I think there are two possible issues that are causing this.

I am used to installing .net manually and now I learned through the visual studio documentation that if you install the latest visual studio and install blazor frameworks through it, the latest .net is installed automatically. So if your organization installed .net already and visual studio professional there might be conflicting files.

If there is already .net and there might be conflicting you can install this program that I found on forum which completely wiped .net from my pc. After I used this and installed .net and it worked instantly. I also had the issue of certificate not allowing me to test my programs even as HTTP. This did not happen after I used this program:


https://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/microsoft_net_framework_cleanup_tool,1.html
I found it useful and it was not a virus for me. It also worked on Windows 11.

I would not run the program if it is a last resort, as again it is a
program on forums so be careful. I have ran anti virus and it did not
detect trojans or any malware of some sort after and during the use of
it.

